# Scroll AppBarLayout to specific Y location

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

I'm trying to figure out how to scroll AppBarLayout to a specific vertical location.

setExpanded is good, but not enough.

I need something between expanded and collapsed

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try collapsing toolbar layout

Comment: @NileshRathod The collapsing toolbar layout is a child in my AppBarLayout

Comment: I think this link help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/34748816/5516760