# how to change AppBarLayout offset programmatically?

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

we can see offset changes by `appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener` but how to change offset programmatically? somtings like appBarLayout.setOffset(y: Float)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AppBarLayout change offset programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748778/appbarlayout-change-offset-programmatically)

Comment: @Zain question is my question, but answer is not!

Answer (score 5):

`AppBarLayout` offset can be changed by:

```
val param = appBarLayout.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
        val behavior = param.behavior as AppBarLayout.Behavior?
        if (behavior != null) {
            behavior.topAndBottomOffset = -500
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code of @Hadi works but it misses a part. When I first tried the code it did not work because the `behavior` was always null. To solve the problem add the following code:

```
// Initialize the AppBarLayout LayoutParams
(yourAppBarLayout.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams).behavior =
  object : AppBarLayout.Behavior() {}
```

Finally, you can set the offset with this method:

```
  fun setAppBarOffset(offset: Int) {
    val param = yourAppBarLayout.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
    val behavior = param.behavior as AppBarLayout.Behavior?
    behavior?.let { it.topAndBottomOffset = offset }
  }
```